# How to normalize text added to the scene after using view.scale()?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

Using pyqt5: QGraphicsView -> QGraphicsScene -> QGraphicsPixmaps.
Assigned view-> scale(1,-1) which seems to flip all text added to the scene:

```
        position = scene.addText("Hello", QFont('Arial Black', 15, QFont.Light))
```

Result: Hello but flipped downwords.

Tried:  `position.setScale(-1)`
Result: olleH

How to make it display as expected?

Comment: Why did you use `scale(1, -1)` in the first place if it does something you don't want?

Comment: Have you tried `position.setScale(1, -1)` or `position.setScale((1, -1))`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because I'm displaying images of different coordinate system that required rescaling. Yes, this give either too many arguments or got tuple error

Comment: @KarinMoe I sincerely doubt that the other coordinate systems use *negative* scaling. If you want to show something at half its size, you should use that factor (`0.5`): the ratio is always proportional, not cumulative. Also, the coordinate system of items is relative to the scene contents, scaling the view is completely irrelevant to that. See the [Graphics View Coordinate System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system)